# Translate a 3d object in WebGL

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, translate

I am trying to move a 3d object in a WebGL app, the problem is I'm getting the error:

> GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glUniformMatrix4fv: wrong uniform function for type

```
// Vertex Shader

    var vertCode =
        'attribute vec4 coordinates;' + 
        'uniform vec4 translation;'+
        'void main(void) {' +
        'gl_Position = coordinates * translation;' +
    '}';

...

// Associating shaders to buffer objects 

         gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);    
         var coordinatesVar = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "coordinates");
         gl.vertexAttribPointer(coordinatesVar, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);   
         gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coordinatesVar); 

// Translation
        var Tx = 0.5, Ty = 0.5, Tz =-0.5;
        var translationMatrix = new Float32Array([
            1,0,0,0,
            0,1,0,0,
            0,0,1,0,
            Tx,Ty,Tz,1
         ]);

         var translation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'translation');
         gl.uniformMatrix4fv(translation, false, translationMatrix);

// Draw

    gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.viewport(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Comment: Saw your comment about translating z axis. You might find [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html) helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the uniform `translation` has to be `mat4` and not `vec4`.
This causes the `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error, because `glUniformMatrix4fv` does not match to the type `vec4`.

Further, the vector has to be multiplied to the matrix from the right in the vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 coordinates; 
uniform mat translation;
void main(void) {
    gl_Position = translation * coordinates; 
}
```

See [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations):

> Furthermore, the *-operator can be used for matrix-vector products of the corresponding dimension, e.g.:
>
> ```
> vec2 v = vec2(10., 20.);
> mat2 m = mat2(1., 2.,  3., 4.);
> vec2 w = m * v; // = vec2(1. * 10. + 3. * 20., 2. * 10. + 4. * 20.)
> ```
>
> **Note that the vector has to be multiplied to the matrix from the right**.
>   
>   If a vector is multiplied to a matrix from the left, the result corresponds to to multiplying a column vector to the transposed matrix from the right. This corresponds to multiplying a column vector to the transposed matrix from the right:
>   Thus, multiplying a vector from the left to a matrix corresponds to multiplying it from the right to the transposed matrix:
>
> ```
> vec2 v = vec2(10., 20.);
> mat2 m = mat2(1., 2.,  3., 4.);
> vec2 w = v * m; // = vec2(1. * 10. + 2. * 20., 3. * 10. + 4. * 20.)
> ```

---

Note, if you want to multiply the vector to the matrix form the right,

```
gl_Position = coordinates * translation;
```

then you have to transpose the matrix. `uniformMatrix4fv` would transpose the matrix, if the 2nd argument would be set `true`:

```
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(translation, true, translationMatrix);
```

Comment: Thank you, there is one small issue, translating by the z axis doesn't work. I added the drawing code to my first post

Comment: @MikeS What does it mean *"translating by the z axis doesn't work"*? Do expect that the object gets smaller or greater when translating along the z axis. That won't happen without perspective projection.

Comment: @MikeS Yes of course, the z coordinate affects the depth value. With orthographic (parallel) projection you can't "see" an effect when changing the z coordinate. If you translate the along z by a grater amount, then the object will disappear, because it is clipped by the near or far plane. You would have to use perspective projection to see an effect.